# Getting the sum of a specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a maintenance table named `ticket` table and a transaction table called `workplan`.

Ticket table contains `tickedID`, `ticketName`, `startdate`,`estimated time of completion` and `total number of hours` columns.

And then `workplan` table has `workplanID`,  `ticketID(foreignkey)`, `currentdate` , `ticket name`, `no of hours`, and `hours remained` columns.

For instance:

I have ticket entry as shown below.

```
ticket ID / ticket name  / start date    / estimated time of c.  /total number of hours

1           /sample name / 05.21.2013 /  05.23.2013             / 21hours
```

and the next table represents the `workplan`.

```
workplanID  / ticket ID / currentdate    / ticket name  / no of hours    / hours remained

 1001       /1          / may.21.2013    /sample name     /3             /18
```

...`Workplan ID is autogenerated.`

If the user manage his/her workplan. The current date will automatically derived. The user will input his/her no of hours.

My question is how can i get the difference between the total number of hours from the ticket table and the hours remained in the workplan table?

so if the user has managed his workplan again the next day,

```
workplanID  / ticket ID / currentdate    / ticket name  / no of hours    / hours remained

 1001       /1           / may.21.2013  /sample name /3                    /18  

 1002       /1           / may.22.2013  /sample name /4                    /14
```

Im using vb.net and sqlserver as my backend.

(binding source)

Comment: Try to add your VB.net code that you are using for better explaining your situation.

Answer (score 0):

the lower value of the `hours_remained` per ticket will always be on the last user update.
so:

```
SELECT total_number_of_hours - MIN(hours_remained)
FROM   workplan, Ticket 
WHERE  Ticket.ticket_ID = workplan.ticket_ID;
```